# Trying to showMessageDialog using JOptionPane upon press of a button

Tags: java, button, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
public class MyFirstGUI extends JFrame {
    public MyFirstGUI() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBackground(new Color(255, 155, 62));
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nice");
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 6, 117, 29);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
    
}
```

problem is that button does not give an output when it is pressed. havent tried many solutions since i really dont know where to go with this one. should be noted that im using WindowsBuilder on Eclipse IDE

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame() - call a constructor first

Comment: See https://www.guru99.com/java-swing-gui.html for an example

Comment: If a correct `main` method is added, where a `MyFirstGUI` instance is created, pressing the button will work and show the message dialog correctly. However, using `null` layout in swing is not advised, use proper [LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead. All in all, I would suggest you to work through the basics of the [java swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to get the hang of it.

Comment: this code works fine for me when the class `MyFirstGUI` is called from a main method like this:- `new MyFirstGUI().setVisible(true);`